# discord bot how can i get a username in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, usernametoken

this is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `[ done ] the @ gold  succes`) {
        message.channel.send('!addinvites @username_who_write_in_code  50');
    } 
});

client.login(token);
```

i dont know how can i get it  nodejs username who write in the code
i try it just simple but not working any pepole name
how can i give it the user name?

Answer (score 0):

In the API, `message.author` gives the message's author, which can be used to find the username. However, pings in `discord.js` work differently than in channel, requiring the user's ID rather than their username. Here's a quick example:

```js
...
message.channel.send("!addinvites <@${message.author.id}> 50");
...
```